# How to access properties of an object if it was created using a constructor function

Tags: javascript, oop

This is my first question on stackoverflow and I am complete beginner in javascript. I was reading about object oriented programming in javascript using this article ,http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know>. In the section named "OOP in javascript", it describes two ways of creating and object:

```
var myObj = {name:"Richard", profession:"Developer"};
```

I know you can access the propertise of this object by

```
myObj.name // "Richard"
```

The Second way the article describes of creating an object is

```
    function People (name, profession) {} 
    var richard = new People (“Richard”, “Developer”)
```

How do I access the name property of this object ??

***Also I haven't read the rest of the article past this topic. I am stuck until this concept is cleared.***

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor function you need to do something like this:

```
function People (name, profession) {
    this.name = name;
    this.profession = profession;
}
```

Then you can access the properties like you did with the first method.

```
richard.name // 'Richard'
```

Remember that the constructor is nothing but an ordinary function. Calling it with `new` just means that it gets an empty object as its receiver, i.e the `this` value inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

the second way is called the constructor pattern.
for which you have to modify your code like below

```
function People (name, profession) {
 this.name = name;
 this.profession = profession;
}
```

in the above code "`this`" refers to the individual instances that you would create with the "`new`" operator.

now we create the object.

```
var richard = new People (“Richard”, “Developer”);
```

and then access the properties like

```
richard.name;
richard.profession;
```

**explained well** [here](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript) with great information on other ways to create objects.